# What are the most popular web statistic scripts?

Tags: statistics

What are the **popular** web statistic scripts/web log analyzers? I'm searching for popular web statistic scripts like [wusage](http://www.boutell.com/wusage/), WebStat or WebAlizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) or [Awstat](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

Another solution is [Pion Core](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-platform). This is the open source edition of the Pion analytics platform. However, it's more of a general-purpose analytics platform (which includes packet sniffing analytics), not just a log analyzer. It has log analyzing capabilities though.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) is far and above the most popular.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm interested in scripts that are installed on host side.

Answer (score 1):

I thought webtrends was the big boys in this market. Remember they became a part of NetIQ then split off agian?

Most people now use a hosted service such as GA, CrazyEgg.com, or GetClicky.com  Its a lot more convenient for someone in management to access these reports, then to pay for a licence of software to install on your hardware.