# Self hosted Web Analytics like urchin

Tags: iis7, analytics

I would like some cheap/free web analytic software to be used on my windows server (Server 2008). urchin seems to be way expensive. please provide me some good recommendations.

Comment: Does this question help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5256/what-are-the-most-popular-web-statistic-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piwik is open source (free) and is self hosted. I believe woopra is the same but haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

[Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

[Mint](http://www.haveamint.com/) is fairly popular. I haven't used it, but it looks great and has received good press in the past. It is a self-hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

Open Web Analytics is one of the best http://www.openwebanalytics.com/

You can view click streams and so much more by the IP

Answer (score 0):

There are good alternatives to Urchin. The best one that I've found is Angelfish. I've been working with the demo version for a week now and I really like it.

http://analytics.angelfishstats.com/