# Is there any alternative to web analytics websites?

Tags: traffic, analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self hosted Web Analytics like urchin](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/self-hosted-web-analytics-like-urchin)

There are sites that provide web analytics solutions. But I don not want dependence to external sites and I want embed an analyzer in my PHP-based website. Is there such off-the-shelf solution so I can embed it in my site with no dependency to other sites? What is pros and cons of each one? Which one is most extensible?